# How to make inherited form full screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having some trouble trying to get a windows form project go full screen and to hide the taskbar. I am inheriting forms from a master form. When I add the following code it still shows the task bar at the bottom.

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
```

When I try the above code in a different win forms project without inherited forms it works.

What do I need to do in inherited forms to get the form to go full screen?

Comment: In what way is it "inherited"? Are any of those properties being modified by the inherited form class?

Comment: It inherits controls from a master form I have tried to modify them in both the master form and the child form.

Comment: The top answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen) is highly upvoted.  I would assume it works.  Note the caveat about the order of setting the properties.  Maybe the problem is that you're setting the bounds when you don't need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decide: Either maximize the form (which always makes sure the TaskBar is still visible) or set the dimensions manually. I suggest you remove the `WindowState` line.

Another failsafe way would be to hide the TaskBar from your code, for example as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022789/hide-taskbar-in-winforms-application).