# Why does setting Params.WndParent allow you to Alt-Tab to an activex app in IE

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-7, internet-explorer-6

I asked this question "[ActiveX pop-up dialogue window hides IE from tasklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016683/activex-pop-up-dialogue-window-hides-ie-from-tasklist%20%22%22)" and got an answer but not an explanation.

Basically I had to set the `Params.WndParent`but the question I have now is why? Why does this solve the problem (cause it does)?

Comment: Do you mean Tab or do you mean Alt+Tab?

Answer (score 2):

The [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776822%28VS.85%29.aspx) of which windows appear in the taskbar tells you the answer to this question:

> The Shell creates a button on the taskbar whenever an application creates a window that isn't owned. To ensure that the window button is placed on the taskbar, create an unowned window with the [WS_EX_APPWINDOW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) extended style. To prevent the window button from being placed on the taskbar, create the unowned window with the **WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW** extended style. As an alternative, you can create a hidden window and make this hidden window the owner of your visible window.

However, the rules stated there are a little opaque. [Raymond Chen summarises the rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/29/46371.aspx) as follows:

> There are some basic rules on which
>   windows go into the taskbar. In short:
>
> - If the WS_EX_APPWINDOW extended style is set, then it will show (when
>     visible).
> - If the window is a top-level unowned window, then it will show
>     (when visible).
> - Otherwise it doesn't show.

Setting WndParent in CreateParams in the linked question means that the window <strike>is no longer a top-level window</strike>becomes an owned top-level window.  Thanks for Sertac and Rob for correcting me.

Comment: The particular one in the referred question rather becomes an "owned top-level" window.

Comment: @Sertac Is that right? If a window has a parent, then is the parent also the owner?

Comment: The parent is never the owner because "[a window can have a parent or an owner but not both](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/15/9978691.aspx)." And since they're mutually exclusive, the same parameter is used for both in `CreateWindowEx`, and the value that gets passed to that parameter is `CreateWindowEx` is kept in `Params.WndParent`.

Comment: @David I've read the links but if my understanding is correct then those articles deal with the dialogue not being on the task bar. In the question IE is Still on the task bar but is not in the <alt>Tab task-List when the dialogue is displayed. Are you saying the setting filter through to IE?

Answer (score 0):

Under a hood Delphi's VCL method `ShowModal` enumerates all visible thread windows and disables all of them (before showing your modal window pop-up). IE6 ActiveX container does nothing to prevent such manipulation with own windows. ActiveX controls very unsecure in IE6, they do what they want. So we get only some disabled IE windows and one active pop-up window on screen. But if the window is disabled, it can't be selected in the task list. Also your pop-up window has `bsToolwindow` property (or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW originally in Windows API) which says that it should not be visible in task list (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> switching, Explorer taskbar). As a result, we have no windows at all from IE that can be activated through <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

This only applies to windows that do not have a parent. For Delphi's ActiveX controls, forms don't have parent by default (except main Form). When you assign parent to your Form, and don't use `ShowModal` method (in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016683/activex-pop-up-dialogue-window-hides-ie-from-tasklist) `Show` method used) you are preventing this situation. In that case, IE windows don't change their original properties.